# How to show Document Set Version?

Tags: 2010, document-library, versioning, document-set, version-history

In SharePoint 2010, there is a new content type called Document Set that allows users to work with multiple documents as a single work product.

In our case, the Document Set's version number is very important to our users, and this Document Set version history increases every time you go to

- Document Set -> Manage -> Capture Version

and you can see the version history of the Document Set by clicking on the Document Set's Version History (this is the version we are interested in)

[image]

However, SharePoint seems to only expose the Document Set's metadata version in the "Version" column. I call this the metadata version because this will only increase if you make changes to the document set's properties, and not if you update the documents inside. This is what I mean by metadata version:

[image]

As you can probably tell, the problem is that in the "Version" column of the document library, all of the document sets show a value of 1.0 (since we never updated the metadata), when the document set version is actually 5.0 or 6.0, since we have updated the documents inside the document sets multiple times.

How do we show the Document Set Version instead of the metadata version to the users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version history of a document set is stored in the propertybag of the document set itself as xml.
In this post this is explained:
[How to retrieve document set version history](http://www.itidea.nl/index.php/how-to-retrieve-document-set-version-history/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and for writing such a comprehensive blog post!